# php mysql insert memory issues

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP mysql code that does an insert into the table (shown below). On my box at home it seemed to run fine but on my hosted production server I am getting unbelievable memory over runs and slow downs.

```
Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
uid int(1)  No       
CUID    int(11) No    
AUID    int(11) No       
user    varchar(10) No       
position    varchar(15) No       
User Added By   varchar(10) No       
Added On    datetime    No       Indexes

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  uid 17196   A   No  
AUID    BTREE   No  No  AUID    9   A   No  
user    BTREE   No  No  user    150 A   No  
CUID    BTREE   No  No  CUID    3439    A   No  


Space usage:
Data    794,776 B
Index   605,184 B
Total   1,367   KiB

Row Statistics:
 Format  dynamic
 Rows    17,196
 Row length ø    46
 Row size ø  81 B
 Next autoindex  27,104
```

When I go to the web page where the form is I fill out the form and insert into this table. The first time the speed is *reasonable*. The second time the page takes 10s of seconds to complete and when I check the memory logs etc on the hosting server the RAM hits all the limits.

```
From ▴  To  aCPU    mCpu    aEP mEP lEP aMEM    mMEM    lMEM    MemF    MepF
02-27 10:08 02-27 10:09 12  62  1   3   20  359.1M  4.0G    4.0G    1   0
02-27 10:07 02-27 10:08 0   0   0   0   20  4.1M    4.1M    4.0G    0   0
02-27 10:06 02-27 10:07 0   0   0   0   20  4.1M    4.1M    4.0G    0   0
02-27 10:05 02-27 10:06 0   0   0   0   20  4.1M    4.1M    4.0G    0   0
02-27 10:04 02-27 10:05 25  62  1   4   20  22.5M   59.8M   4.0G    0   0
02-27 10:00 02-27 10:05 0   0   0   2   20  4.6M    22.7M   4.0G    0   0
02-27 09:00 02-27 10:00 0   75  0   4   20  5.8M    452.7M  4.0G    0   0
02-27 08:00 02-27 09:00 0   0   0   1   20  284K    18.1M   4.0G    0   0
```

Note the 4.0G in the first line.

I am really stuck as to what this could be. The hosting place is using suPHP and I have heard there used to be bugs in this (but that was from a few years ago).

Maybe it is unrealistic, but doing a single insert into this table (which is relatively small, I think) should not cause memory issues all over the place.  Here is the insert statement:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO call_member SET user="'.$user.'", position="'.$position.'", CUID="'.$CUID.'", AUID="'.$apparatus.'", `LOSAP Added By`="'.$losap_added_by.'", `Added On`=NOW()');
```

Now, I know I need to switch to mysqli.  That is in the short term plans.

What would be killing the server?  I worked with the hosting company and their server appears fine.

I am not *completely* sure this is causing the memory issue but it happens every time I run this piece of code. So, I *believe* it is the cause. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[added more code]

```
$query = 'SELECT USER FROM member WHERE USER = "'.strtolower($user).'"';
$ck = squery( $query );
$num_entries = mysql_num_rows( $ck );
$row_person = mysql_fetch_assoc($ck);

$query = 'SELECT USER FROM call_member WHERE CUID='.$_REQUEST['CUID'].' AND USER = "'.strtolower($user).'" LIMIT 1';
$ck = squery( $query );

if( $num_entries == 1 && mysql_num_rows($ck) == 0 )
{       

    if( $num_entries == 1 )
    {
            $query = 'INSERT INTO call_member SET LOSAP="'.$row_person['LOSAP'].'", ccnumber ="' . $ccnumber . '", position="'.$position.'", CUID="'.$CUID.'", apparatus="'.$apparatus .'", `LOSAP Added By`="'.$user_added_by.'", `Added On`=NOW()';
            $result = squery( $query );
    }
    else
    {
            print '<div>Error: Could not find a user number or unique person for "'.$user.'" or the person is not a current member.</div>';
    }
}
```

and I have a function squery defined in an include function:

```
function squery( $query  ) 
{
    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    print mysql_error();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What process is using that much memory, mysql or apache?

Comment: Yesterday I was running "top" on the hosting box while I was doing some of these things. There were multiple php processes being created and a couple of them went <defunct>.

Comment: We need to see your code to answer your question. Also, your field names should NEVER have spaces in them! It can cause all sorts of problems. Underscores or hyphens are much better, I prefer underscores.

Comment: So, it might not be *exactly* the mysql insert but something to do with it and php, but the rest of the website runs "fine". It just appears to be this part of the code.

Comment: Right so we need to see the code. When you were running "top" on the box what was the process name? Was it mysql, apache, or something else? Normally top gives you the name of the process. This would help you figure out the what is causing the issue, the php code or the mysql statement.

Comment: Also do you have phpmyadmin or something running? Try echoing out your insert statement and then use phpmyadmin to run it. Does it take a long time? If not then it is definitely something in your php code. Sounds to me like you are getting stuck in a never ending loop of code.

Comment: Pitchinnate: I did echo the mysql and run in PHPmyadmin. It was a fast add...  Ok. maybe that is a red herring (on my part).  So, maybe it is back to a PHP issue.  (sorry guys)

Comment: Ok, so I just tried it again with a single time through my page (with the INSERT). It started a PHP command (as viewed in top). The CPU went way up on the PHP command and then the PHP went <defunct> and about 10s later it went away.

Comment: Should your squery method return the result or is that a typo?

Comment: FYI your going to get hammered for having a Request variable directly in your sql query without sanitizing it first.

Comment: After the php goes defunct and disappears has the insert actually ran? Is there a new row in the DB?

Comment: Yes, after the php goes defunct there is a new row in the DB.  (understood on sanitizing - I am relatively new at the DB part.)

Comment: Psychic:  Yes, type. It does return the $result;

Comment: I suppose I could run the php code "offline" (ie not through the web page) and see how fast or slow it runs. I could try some timing of it through there.

Comment: So, is there a way to find out why the PHP process is going <defunct> or is allocating so much memory?  I guess that it is the actual question as it would/should lead to a solution.

Comment: After each section of code or every few lines add something like `echo 'done'; die();` I would try adding it right after `$row_person = ...` see if it takes a long time or if it finishes instantly. If it is done instantly trying moving the echo and die down farther, see if you can figure out what section of code is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your squery method:

function squery( $query  )

```
{
    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    print mysql_error();
}
```

Should have a:

```
return $result;
```

at the end.

Comment: Yes. It actually does. The copy/paste missed it.